# QuestPDF: Correct way to bottom right corner alignment

Tags: c#, pdf-generation

I am using Quest PDF to generate some PDF documents. What I want to achieve is an address in the bottom right corner of the page. These will be spread across multiple lines, address line 1, address line 2, address line 3 etc.

However I am struggling with the correct way to bottom align something. I can force bottom alignment using padding like below however this is not reliable as text above could push it down.

```
column.Item().PaddingBottom(250);

column.Item().AlignRight().Text(Line1);
column.Item().AlignRight().Text(Line2);
column.Item().AlignRight().Text(Line3);
column.Item().AlignRight().Text(Line4);
column.Item().AlignRight().Text(Telephone);
```

I have also tried using the `Extend()` method alongside `AlignBottom()` which works, but only seems to show Line1? Using AlignBottom like the below example does not work and the text in the middle of the page?

```
column.Item().AlignBottom().AlignRight().Text(Line1);
```

I am little lost so any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this work, by grouping the line elements into their own column and aligning that to the bottom alongside using `ExtendVertical()`

```
column.Item().ExtendVertical().AlignBottom().AlignRight().PaddingBottom(5).Column(col =>
{
    col.Item().Text(Line1);
    col.Item().Text(Line2);
    col.Item().Text(Line3);
    col.Item().Text(Line4);
    col.Item().Text(Telephone);
});
```

I also decided to add a little padding to the bottom as it was a little close to the footer for my liking.